# VMWare Virtual Center unrecoverable error: (mks)

Tags: windows, windows-7, vmware-esx, 64-bit

I have a ESX3i, build 207095 and i'm having a problem connecting to my VM's using the vmware remote console.

On my PC always gives me an error about vmare-remotemks. I can do all of the tasks using VI client, but when a try to open remote console it breaks, the only thing that apears on the black screen is "unknown MKS Event".

I can't find a solution to my problem, and i really need to be able to start a remote console from my PC.

On my laptop the error doesn't occurs, both machines are Windows 7 x64.

Thanks,

JGanhão

Answer (score 1):

Is there a firewall between your machine and the ESX host in question? Remote console uses an additional port (902 TCP) which may be getting blocked somewhere along the line.

Answer (score 0):

In the file /etc/vmware/config, verify that the following parameter is configured (and if not, then configure it) :
vmauthd.server.alwaysProxy = "TRUE"

To do this, type :
        cd /etc/vmware

Then, type : 
        nano config

In the file, add the line below :

vmauthd.server.alwaysProxy = "TRUE"

After adding the line, restart the vmkauthd service. Type :

service vmware-vmkauthd restart

More informations on :

http://communities.vmware.com/thread/175881

And in particular the following response, explaining that it is a bug and that the line we added is a workaround :

"Thanks Wil. Yup, the vmauthd.server.alwaysProxy=TRUE is the magic; as soon as I set that on the ESX host then I only see traffic on 443 and 902. Interesting that there is a reference from one of the VMware guys here in the forums dating back to 2006 saying that seeing traffic on 903 was a "bug" that they would be fixing and that "vmauthd.server.alwaysProxy" was an undocumented workaround. Guess it wasn't at the top of the "fix list" "